# Git post-receive hook for `Everything up-to-date`

Tags: git

We are using the post-receive hook on a server to do some processing when there is a `git push` from client.

This work only when there is something new to push, but when `Everything up-to-date`, post-receive hook will not be executed.

We do want to do something when there is really no update, is it possible?

Comment: You should try it with the `pre-receive` hook instead of `post-receive`, if it is possible at all.

Comment: @lanzz - I was just trying `pre-receive` now (just a plain echo), and it seems it doesn't fire when `Everything up-to-date` either...

Comment: What kind of think are you trying to do in case there was no update?