# Keeping github in sync with a different server

Tags: git, github, synchronization, mirror

I want to use github (Enterprise) for managing code, issue tracking and so on. I also have a requirement that I need the repository to be on another server.

There's a bunch of posts on mirroring, but they seem to only work one way (github -> server sync).

I'd like to be able to push to both github *and* to the server, and I want things to be in sync. Is there a clean way to achieve this?

Comment: You seem to be asking two things--how to synchronize repos, and how to push to multiple remotes. Which is it?

Comment: I know how to push to multiple repositories. The question is, if I push to the server remote (let's call it "server"), how do I ensure that it reflects in the one hosted on github (and vice versa)?

Comment: You can't do that both ways, can you? What if people push to different repositories at the same time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeping git mirrors in sync at all times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851181/keeping-git-mirrors-in-sync-at-all-times)